# Moq'ing a return value method from within a void method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I'm currently Moq'ing - or attempting to Moq - a class that would insert data into a database.

I am mocking two interfaces and through the use of DI setting them to the constructor of the following 'Facade' class.

Currrently all of my tests run and pass, but I need some guidance on how I can set the returned bool value of the shown 'SaveServiceMessage' method.

Currently I call the 'SynchEmployee' method which is void, internally within this method the 'SaveServiceMessage' is called. Within SaveServiceMessage, I am calling the mocked object method of the constructor 'SaveMessage', this is the method that would be accessing the database in the real non-Moq'd object..

What I need to know, is how I can Moq and get the boolean true or false value of the 'SaveServiceMessage'. I'm new to Moq'ing so hopefully you guys can guide me.

This is my current test:

```
[Test]
    public void TestSynchroniseEmployeeMethod()
    {
        var employee = new Employee();
        {
            employee.AOID = "A1";
            employee.ID = 1;
        }

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        var serviceClientMock = new Mock<IService>();
        var serviceMessageReposMock = new Mock<IServiceMessageRepos>();

        var TestFacade = new Facade(serviceClientMock.Object, serviceMessageReposyMock.Object);

        TestFacade.SynchroniseEmployee(employee, guid);


        serviceMessageReposMock.Verify(x => x.SaveMessage(It.IsAny<ServiceMessage>()), Times.Exactly(1));

        serviceClientMock.Verify(x => x.SendServiceMessage(It.IsAny<ServiceMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(1));
    }

public class Facade
{

   IService _serviceMessage;
   IServiceRepos _serviceMessageRepos

    public Facade(IService serviceMessage, IServiceRepos serviceMessageRepos)
    { 
       _serviceMessage = serviceMessage;
       _serviceMessageRepos = serviceMessageRepos;
    }

    public bool SaveServiceMessage(ServiceMessage message, Guid correlationId, ConversationStatus status)
    {
        if (message != null)
        {
            message.CorrelationID = correlationId;

            _serviceMessageRepos.SaveMessage(message);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void SynchEmployee(Employee employee, Guid messageId)
    {
        var employees = new List<Employee>();
        employees.Add(employee);

        var message = new ServiceMessage(employee.ID, null, ServiceMessageType.EmployeeSyncRequest, Guid.NewGuid());

        message.ID = employee.ID.ToString();
        SaveServiceMessage(message, message.CorrelationID, ConversationStatus.NEW); 
        TransmitServiceMessage(message); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: The `SynchEmployee` method calls `SaveServiceMessage` but throws away the return value (your bool). Moq can't change that, when you call `SynchEmployee` from your test.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks for your reply, yes I can see as you say that the returned value is being ignored and not used. In your opinion, are my tests ok?

Comment: Why do you want/need to know the return value of SaveServiceMessage(), it is not used in the code.  If you are trying to check whether the code works correctly with a null message, then the verify on SaveMessage() will probably suffice.  SaveServiceMessage() is public. Is it called from elsewhere?  What should happen in SynchEmployeed() if SaveServiceMessage() returns false.  Should TransmitServiceMessage() still be called?

Answer (score 1):

*SynchEmployee()* takes in an Employee and a Guid (messageId) and calls *IServiceRepos.SaveMessage()* on a message. There seem to be no options, so the single test should suffice but...

We do not check anything about the saved message...

Should the saved message be using the messageId? We do not check that it is - it is not, we create a new id when creating the message. If the saved message should contain the passed in messageId then the verify should check this.

Was the employee Id read from the Employee and put into the message (it seems to be used twice, once in the ctor, once afterwards)

Is the message type correct?

There is a verify in the test for SendServiceMessage() which is never called.

We add the employee to a local list of employees and then do nothing further with it.

We set the message id to the employee id - is this correct?  If yes, then why are we passing in the messageId?

In the ctor of ServiceMessage() we pass in a newly created GUID and then set the ID of the message to the employeeId.  Is the last parameter on the ctor the ID. if so, can we pass in the value at this point instead of setting it afterwards.

Personal preference: Having the **new ServiceMessage(...)** call does some damage to the testability. If we passed in a service to create the message then we could just verify that the service was called with the correct parameters and return a dummy message that we can use in the verify calls instead of having to write comparators for the message.

We pass a ConversationStatus into *SaveServiceMessage()* that is never used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
serviceMessageReposMock.SetUp(x => x.SaveServiceMessage(It.IsAny<ServiceMessage>(), GUId, status)).Returns(true);
```

This way the `SaveServiceMessage` will not get actually called, but still can verify the output.